# To Find the average of a particular type in MongooseJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MongoDB collection "Marks" as shown below

```
 _id   Student_id   Subject  Mark
   1    111          AAA      9
   2    111          BBB      5
   3    111          CCC      7
   4    222          AAA      10
   5    222          CCC      6
   6    222          BBB      8
```

I need to find the average mark scored by student_id=111 in 3 subjects using **MONGOOSEJS** .I got a solution

```
var Mark = mongoose.model('mark', new Schema({
  Student_id: Number,
  Subject: String,
  Mark: Number
}));

Mark.aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: '$Student_id',
        markAvg: { $avg: '$Mark'}
    }}
], function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(results);
    }
}
);
```

Output is

```
    [ { _id: 222, markAvg: 8 }, { _id: 111, markAvg: 7 } ]
```

I Want only `{_id:111,markAvg:7}` when I pass student_id:111 as parameter.
Anyone please suggest an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/#_S_match) element to the top of your pipeline to filter the documents of the collection to just the ones you want as input to the `$group`:

```
Mark.aggregate([
    { $match: { Student_id: 111 } },
    { $group: {
        _id: '$Student_id',
        markAvg: { $avg: '$Mark'}
    }}
], function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

Comment: Its Working.My output is {"_id":"111","markAvg":3.5}.I cahnged            **_id: '$Student_id'**  in code to **Student_id** to change the output variable name,but it caused error. Is there any way to change o/p display variable from '_id' to 'Student_id'? i.e **{"Student_id":"111","markAvg":3.5}**

Comment: @dany Add a [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/#_S_project) operation to the end of the pipeline to do that.